# Pytesseract does not recognize numbers despite trying every -psm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I've been trying to get some numbers from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuK1z.png) but pytesseract only gives me random letters. I've tried many -psm options but it does not seem to work. Here's the code I'm using:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("Test.png"), config="--psm 6"))
```

What could I do to make it more succesful?

Comment: Read up on [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

Comment: Tesseract doesn't like light text on black background. It does better with dark text on light background. Also I've notice that sometimes Tesseract has difficulty if the image is cropped too tighly and characters are close to the edge of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("vuK1z.png", 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 6 '
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config=custom_config)
print(text)
```

Result

```
550,000
```